# jquery selector doesn't work when html is replaced!

Tags: jquery, html, selector

Please, help me with following problem:

```
<!-- this is the visible code -->
<div id="divid">{some default content}<img class="img" src="GoNextArrow.jpg" alt=""></div>

<!-- this is a hidden list of contents -->
<div style="display: none;">
    <div id="divid1">{some content 1}<img class="img" src="GoNextArrow.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div id="divid2">{some content 2}<img class="img" src="GoNextArrow.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div id="divid3">{some content 3}<img class="img" src="GoNextArrow.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div id="divid4">{some content 4}<img class="img" src="GoNextArrow.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div id="divid5">{some content 5}<img class="img" src="GoNextArrow.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>

<!-- this is an jquery script which replace the #divid with any of divid1-divid5 -->
$('#divid').hide().html(elem.html()).fadeIn();  
<!-- elem is a variable, divid1 to divid5, e.g. var elem = $j('#divid'+id);  -->

<!-- I need a rollover effect, I made it so: -->
$('img.img').hover(function () {
    $(this).attr('src', 'GoNextArrowHover.jpg');
}, function () {
    $(this).attr('src', 'GoNextArrow.jpg');
});
```

This works well for the first div divid, but doesn't for divid1-divid5 when these are loaded instead of divid.
Where is my mistake??

Thanks!

Comment: Can you implement you code demonstrating the problem in http://jsfiddle.net/ to aid in debugging please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`delegate()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to manage events inside the `divid` container.

```
$('#divid').delegate('img.img','mouseenter',function () {
    $(this).attr('src', 'GoNextArrowHover.jpg');
})
  .delegate('img.img','mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).attr('src', 'GoNextArrow.jpg');
});
```

Or if possible, make the `<img>` an `<a>` element instead, and just do it with CSS using the `background-image` property:

```
#divid > div > a {
    background-image:url(GoNextArrow.jpg);
    background-repeate:no-repeat;
}
#divid > div > a:hover {
    background-image:url(GoNextArrowHover.jpg);
}
```

You'll need a few more properties to make it just right

Comment: Using .delegate() is a good idea... I'm beginner in jquery, I didn't know about .delegate(). Thanks!

Comment: @Denis: You're welcome. You can always use `.delegate()` in place of `.live()`. They both use *event delegation*, but `.delegate()` let's you focus it on a particular portion of the page so it is a more efficient approach.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of re-binding `.hover()` every time, just use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and it will work for all current and future elements that match your selector, example...

```
$('.hoverme').live('hover', function(event) {
    if (event.type == 'mouseenter') {
        $(this).attr('src', 'GoNextArrowHover.jpg');
    }
    else {
        $(this).attr('src', 'GoNextArrow.jpg');
    } 
});
```

Comment: Your second function your passing will have no effect because `.live()` can accept only one handler.

Comment: I don't meant to pick on you ;o), but should probably be noted that your update will not work after jQuery 1.4.2. For some bizarre (IMO) reason they started reporting the event as `mouseenter` in 1.4.3.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.html()` to replace the contents of an element, you are creating new child elements (`img` in your case), so you need to rebind your `hover` handler to the new `img` element after each call to `.html()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery live to bind the hover attempt. Live mens that the function will apply to all future elements that match the selector too.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

$(selector).live('hover', function() {});

Comment: This won't work because `hover` isn't a real event; moreover, `hover` requires two callbacks while `live` takes only one.

Comment: It can in the latest version of jquery

Comment: From the site: As of jQuery 1.4.1 the hover event can be specified (mapping to mouseenter and mouseleave, which, in turn, are mapped to mouseover and mouseout).

Comment: @casablanca: You were right in your original comment that `.live()` only accepts 1 handler.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into using `replaceWith()`:

```
$('#divid').hide().replaceWith( elem.fadeIn() );
```

If you've already bound functions to events on `elem`, those should persist even after you've swapped `elem` for another element on the page.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/eLD9A/